# Реакция на клик по нескольким элементам управления одновременно

Tags: wpf, .net, события

Нормальное поведение практически любых GUI на клик мышью по одному из контроллов - вызвать Event для этого контролла. Если же в одном месте находится несколько элементов управления, событие вызывается только для "верхнего".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли узнать обо всех таких "попаданиях"? В моём случае есть Canvas с кучей дочерних Ellipse'ов, которые и должны реагировать на клик.

ЗЫ: Не вижу особых проблем для того, чтобы посчитать пересечения вручную, но хотелось бы обойтись без костылей :)

Answer (score 2):

Пишите свой детектор столкновения курсора с объектами, это просто. [wiki/Эллипс](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81) в помощь.

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```

Используйте этот объект для получения координат мыши. Может еще потребоваться линейная конверсия координат из системы координат в которой задан эллипс в систему координат в которой задан курсор или обратно.

Comment: За совет - огромное спасибо, но это немного не то =) Пробежаться по Child'ам, перейти в одну систему координат и проверить коллижн я вполне могу(изначально так и было сделано, только коллижн искался не с самими эллипсами, а с объектами, которые они схематически отображают), просто хотелось бы по возможности использовать стандартные средства. Есть вероятность, к примеру, что внутри стандартных контейнеров реализовано некое разбиение пространства для того чтобы упростить поиск от O(N) до какого-нибудь O(log N). Ну а даже если и нет - всё равно хотелось бы не городить костылей...

Comment: Если внутри .NET реализовано бинарное дерево поиска по всем объектам формы для вызова этого события, а не просто тупой перебор координат всех объектов формы, то остается только пожать им руку.

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку у вас в тегах есть WPF, почитайте про Routed Events, и про их типы — восходящие и нисходящие. Это то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

WPF генерирует щелчок всегда только для лежащего сверху элемента - это не лечится. Но свою проблему вы можете решить так: завести список, в которому будут храниться все эллипсы, над которыми сейчас мышь. В обработчике события MouseEnter эллипса добавлять его в список, а в MouseLeave - удалять. Это всего две строчки. А в клике по любому эллипсу без плясок с координатами используйте этот список.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вот такую штуку (`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`), результаты положительные. Нашел, к сожалению, самостоятельно, но всё равно ОГРОМНОЕ всем спасибо за внимание и советы!

[Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).